# sysctl hook in ios 15 leads to no mobile network connection

Tags: objective-c, hook, theos, sysctl

Hi i am hooking sysctl on ios 15, i have problem after hooking, imei code disappears, sim and mobile network service lose connection, can anyone help me!

Here is code Objective C++ and Logos:

```
int (* original_sysctl)(const int *name, u_int namelen, void *oldp, size_t *oldlenp, const void *newp, size_t newlen);
static int replaced_sysctl(const int *name, u_int namelen, void *oldp, size_t *oldlenp, const void *newp, size_t newlen) {
    int result = original_sysctl(name, namelen, oldp, oldlenp, newp, newlen);
    return result;
}


%ctor {

    MSHookFunction(sysctl, (void*)replaced_sysctl, (void **)&original_sysctl);


}
```

Has anyone encountered this problem and had a solution, please help me, thanks a lot